# find data size of xml type column in db2

Tags: database, db2

I have a table which has a column of data type xml. I want to find the size of data inserted by user in that column. DB2 shows the length of that column is 0.

How can i find the size of data that is present in column of type xml in a table in DB2 database?

Comment: What for? What's your DB2 platform and version?

Comment: its on linux machine. can't say about version but its not that old version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem.

As XML in DB2 is a transient datatype it is stored in its hierarchical form. So what you have to do is to serialize the xml-content (because it's stored in it's "parsed" form) and output it into a serialized data type (e.g. a CLOB).

Take for example the table `xmltable` with the column `content` which is of type XML:

```
SELECT xmltable.*, XMLSERIALIZE(xmltable.content AS CLOB(20M))
    FROM xmltable
```

Be sure to initialize the CLOB large enough, otherwise you'll get an error 22001.